# What is this Rails code doing? synchronously & safely methods being called

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Can someone please break down this piece code for me? I'm not sure exactly what is happening here...

```
   @user.synchronously.delete

   def self.synchronously
     return self.safely
   end

   def synchronously
     return self.safely
   end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably want to look in the `lib` folder to see if there is a plugin named `safely` implemented. If not, search the code base for `safely` and see what comes up.